# Braid and psychonauts wont download

Tags: software-center, games, repository, downloads, installed-programs

I am running ubuntu 12.04 and I am having a problem with downloading Braid and Psychonauts from the ubuntu software center. An error message pops up saying "failed to download repository information". What does that mean?

Comment: Try to run the following in a terminal: `sudo apt-get update` and then try installing the apps again (turn off the Software Center, and then turn it on again before trying, though). You will need to enter your password.

Comment: I got a 401 error in the terminal. Now attempting to download braid...

Comment: Are you under a proxy? If so, you may need to talk to your admin. Otherwise, try choosing a different server in Update Manager (click Settings in the lower left, go to the Ubuntu Software tab, and select the server from Download from). More info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857326

Comment: No, I'm not under a proxy. And besides that, it didn't work changing the server.

Comment: Well, I'm out :) Try contacting Ubuntu support. There's probably an official channel when your purchases don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple mysterious things happened. first of all, I tried installing braid via torrent and a message popped up telling me that I needed new nvdia drivers... so I did. Nvdia! I dont't even have Nvdia cards, but it worked, and the games installed. Then, like, yesterday, I got an email from ubuntu support (even though I hadn't contacted them yet) saying the braid link had been down and was back up now. Funny, huh? Well, at least it's working now.